# URL and json parameters

Tags: json, iis

I saw websites in the format "website/json?h=123456789" and assuming the server is IIS-based, what would be the minimum required software to allow such format.

Is ASP.net enough, or maybe Ajax. Is any database needed at the backend? Is there any documentation or tutorial for something like this? Maybe a sample code in a sample file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL that you see, is used for sending some parameter to the server for processing. It can be a simple MVC application built on .Net or any other platform.

To answer your question - The server may not be IIS, it might be some other web server like APACHE tomcat.

The minimum required software for website depends on what platform the app was built. 
For .Net Web apps you need .Net framework installed on the web server.

AJAX - You do not need any special software as Microsoft provides necessary resources to develop AJAX based applications. You just need to deploy those resources to the web server.

If your application contains only static HTML pages you may not require any database or any programming language, but if your app has dynamic stuff that is rendered based on some logic or some User interaction where you want save some data which can be used later, then you would need a relational database.

If you google you will find lots of information - Check this [link](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question222.htm) and [this one](http://websitesetupguide.com/basic/start.htm) for simple website designing. for .Net you can see these links [Link1](http://webproject.scottgu.com/csharp/helloworld/helloworld.aspx), [Link2](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/), [Link3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywdtth2f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I hope this would give you some insight. If not someone else would have a better explanation which would help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is very helpful. If you don't mind can you please direct me to something specific to Json, like a sample code that handles specific JSON requests in IIS. Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn to use google. there are lots and lots of tutorials and examples. Here are some starter links [link1](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/CreateSimpleAJAXApplication.aspx), [link2](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/basics/hello-world/), [link3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/401903/AJAX-for-Beginners-Part-1-Understanding-ASP-NET-AJ)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, in these past few days I learned a lot from your links and Google :-)